# Sum multiple regular expressions in SQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a string column with values that I extract using regex. The pattern is: `\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}-([\d,.]+)`

There are multiple values that match that pattern and I would like to extract and sum all of them in Oracle SQL.

For example: "text 100 text 200 text". Result: 300.

Thank you!

Comment: Your column data is particularly unnomalized.  You should probably first extract the numbers from text before bringing this data into Oracle.

Comment: That is kind of my question. I want to extract the numbers from the text but because there is many of them I'd like to sum them.

Comment: Please show some real data and expected output.  Your example does not match the pattern you gave. How many numbers after the date?  0 or more? 1 or more? Always 2? Could the string be NULL?  Just the number part NULL? Looks like the number could include decimal places (according to your pattern)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CONNECT BY LEVEL` Statement :

```
WITH t2 AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT ID, regexp_substr(str,'[0-9]+',1,level) AS NMR
    FROM t
 CONNECT BY level <= regexp_count(str,'[0-9]+')
)
SELECT SUM(NVL(NMR,0)) AS "Numeric Result"
  FROM t2
```

together with `regexp_substr()` and `regexp_count()` functions assuming you have a primary key column(`ID`)

If you need row-wise aggregation, then consider using `GROUP BY ID` for the main query :

```
SELECT ID, SUM(NVL(NMR,0)) AS "Numeric Result"
  FROM t2
 GROUP BY ID
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3d6829a5d67d03a0b518857bddc97cce)</kbd>

Comment: This is great. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
SQL> with
  2  test (col) as
  3    (select 'text 100 text 200 text whatever 20' from dual),
  4  tsplit as
  5    (select regexp_substr(col, '[^ ]+', 1, level) val
  6     from test
  7     connect by level <= regexp_count(col, ' ') + 1
  8    )
  9  select sum(val) result
 10  From tsplit
 11  where regexp_like(val, '^\d+$');

    RESULT
----------
       320

SQL>
```

What does it do?

- lines #1 - 3: sample data
- lines #4 - 8 splits sample string into rows - each "word" into its own row
- the final `select` sums numeric values (line #9) that are numbers (`regexp_like`)

Now, depending on *real* data, this might need to be improved, but - generally, should work.